# angular 2 to display and hide a component on mouse enter and leave

Tags: html, css, angular

I have created a component for filter in angular 2 which I have added inside my table header. I want to display  when mouse is on span and when out i want to hide

```
<th>
 <span class="headColor" >{{componentContents.dlHead}}</span>
  <app-data-filter [dataObject]="responseData" [filterBy]="'storeCatelogue'"
 (filteredArray)="filterByArray($event,'storeCatelogue')"></app-data-filter>
</th>
 <th >
  <span class="headColor">{{componentContents.titleHead}}</span>
  <app-data-filter [dataObject]="responseData" [filterBy]="'title'" 
  (filteredArray)="filterByArray($event,'title')" ></app-data-filter>
 </th>
```

But i want to display this filter component on mouse over and hide on mouse out and this should not display all the app-data-filter component i want to display it for that particular header. filter is different for each header so i should display one at a time. I don't have any idea about host listener that how can i use that here as i'm still learning angular 2 so it would be really helpful if i get some guidance or is there any other way

Answer (score 2):

You can use the css :hover selector..

Since you didn't specify the exact structure of your html its hard for me to say how exactly you should implement it.

Lets say for this matter that you want to show the  on table mouse hover, and you table class is 'my-table'.

```
.my-table:hover{
  th{
    display:none;
    }
}
```

You can read about the :hover selector [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp).

**Edit:**

If your html strauctre is something like:

```
<span class='my-toggle-span'>Toggle app filter!</span>

<app-filter class='my-app-filter'></app-filter>
```

Then your css will be

```
.my-toggle-span:hover +.my-app-filter{
display:none;
}
```

The [plus selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) Selects all element that are placed immediately after it.

**Edit 2:**
As opener requested, A javascript based solution:
I don't recommend this approach and any way, Your toggle logic should be handled in your component and not in your html.

```
<span class='my-toggle-span' (mouseenter)="toggle=true;"
 (mouseleave)="toggle=false;">Toggle app filter!</span>

<app-filter *ngIf="toggle" class='my-app-filter'></app-filter>
```

Comment: I dont want to show hide th.I want to display <app-filter> on hover of span

Comment: I want solution in angular2 not css

Comment: There is no need to involve JavaScript in such a simple hide/show operation.. This is just a waste...If you still insist of doing so, you can bind (mouseenter) event to your span and use it to toggle a Boolean that toggle your <app-filter>. Iv'e edited my answer again..

Comment: But i can not write the same code in both the span as it will display both <app-filter> but i want to display only targeted hover span's <app-filter>

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you want to achieve ..  Every span you want to hover and make some action you'll need to add some function call.. you can make one functions for all if that's what you mean ... That's way I wrote you should handle your logic in your component and not it your template...